# IEmailSender outside of the UI project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When using Razor UI to handle registration, you need to implement `IEmailSender` and register it in startup.cs. Is there a way to use a mail class in another class library project within the solution? The mail class is something I would want kept out of the UI project.

I could probably install the nuget package for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` in the class library, but that comes with an entourage of about 50 dependencies.  Is there a better, more lightweight way?

Comment: Adding this as a comment because I can't necessarily answer the question. I'm not very familiar with Razor in .Net Core. However, I did find this: https://kenhaggerty.com/articles/article/aspnet-core-22-smtp-emailsender-implementation They aren't using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` stuff as far as I can tell. Maybe that can at least give you a start.

Comment: Create a service derived from `IEmailSender` that wraps the external mail class library.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks, couldn't see the wood from the trees the other day. Was just the hint I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just having a long evening and the answer wasn't coming to me. A good point was made in the comment about wrapping the external service so I have done exactly that.

Here the `EmailSender` class just wraps my `IMailService` which is implemented in a class library project.

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    private readonly IMailService mailService;

    public EmailSender(IMailService mailService)
    {
        this.mailService = mailService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mailService));
    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => mailService.Send(new string[] { email }, subject, htmlMessage));
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and SOLID implementation

Comment: Best of all is how highly decoupled it is. :P